# how to change the destination location for files for merging?

Tags: scripts

```
timestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)
mDir=`dirname $0`
filename=purge_log_$timestamp.log
log=$mDir/log/$filename

purge_path="sf2212f/vendors/jboss5/jboss-eap-6.4/d/log"
bz_purge_retention=60
log_compress_retention=2

START_TIME=$(date +%s)
echo "*** Purge Log Files for path [$purge_path] Started :: $(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)" >> $log

# purge the old files in log folder
find $purge_path/* -name "webapp_dbs1*bz2" -type f -mtime +"${bz_purge_retention}" -print -delete >> $log
find $purge_path/* -name "webapp_access_d*bz2" -type f -mtime +"${bz_purge_retention}" -print -delete >> $log
find $purge_path/* -name "eventprocess_d*bz2" -type f -mtime +"${bz_purge_retention}" -print -delete >> $log
find $purge_path/* -name "server_u_dbs1*bz2" -type f -mtime +"${bz_purge_retention}" -print -delete >> $log

echo "*** Purge Log Files for path [$purge_path] Completed :: $(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)" >> $log

echo "*** Compress Files for path [$purge_path] Started :: $(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)" >> $log

#compress the old files in log folder
find $purge_path/* -name "webapp_d*" -type f -mtime +"${log_compress_retention}"|egrep -v '\.bz2'|xargs bzip2 >> $log
find $purge_path/* -name "webapp_access_d*" -type f -mtime +"${log_compress_retention}"|egrep -v '\.bz2'|xargs bzip2 >> $log
find $purge_path/* -name "eventprocess_dbs1*" -type f -mtime +"${log_compress_retention}"|egrep -v '\.bz2'|xargs bzip2 >> $log
find $purge_path/* -name "server_u_d*" -type f -mtime +"${log_compress_retention}"|egrep -v '\.bz2'|xargs bzip2 >> $log

END_TIME=$(date +%s)
echo "*** Compress Files for path [$purge_path] Completed :: $(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)" >> $log

ELAPSED_TIME=$(($END_TIME - $START_TIME))
hr=$(($ELAPSED_TIME / 3600))
hr_mod=$(($ELAPSED_TIME % 3600))
mm=$(($hr_mod / 60))
ss=$(($hr_mod % 60))

echo "*** Purge Log Files for path [$purge_path] took [$ELAPSED_TIME] seconds, Elapsed Time ::  $(date -d $hr:$mm:$ss +%Hh:%Mm:%Ss)"  >> $log
```

Comment: please explain that above script .?

Comment: Try reading the comments in the script .. It's quit self-explanatory. An then, in a terminal, use 'man <cmd>' to learn about command options, t.ex 'man find'.

Comment: It deletes old compressed log files from JBoss and compresses uncompressed log files

Answer (score 1):

It's doing a few things:

- Looking in `/068fs01/vendors/jboss5/jboss-eap-6.4/dbs1/log` for named log files.
- Deleting old (defined by `bz_purge_retention`) "backups" of these log files.
- Creating new bzipped backups if they're older than `log_compress_retention` demands.
- Echoing a load of stuff to tell you what it's doing and how long it took into a common log file (defined at the top of the file).

To use a common phrase: log rotation.

Comment: can u please tell me in compressing side how to change the destination file location?